# Create Custom Dropdown Box in Tinymce in Wordpress for Shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, shortcode

Does anyone know how to create a custom dropdown box in tinymce for Wordpress?
I need it to work with at least wordpress 3.0.

I have searched the internet for a tutorial on this and I cannot find one. A link to a website tutorial would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was already asked some time ago, but as I stumbled across the same problem, I tought I'd answer this question anyways. Maybe it helps someone else.

The comments in the [source of the DropDown-Control](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/master/jscripts/tiny_mce/classes/ui/DropMenu.js) in tinyMCE turned out to be really helpful.

You just need to create a dropdown first, using `createDropMenu()`, then you can call the `add()` method to add items to the dropdown.

```
/**
 * This class is used to create drop menus, a drop menu can be a
 * context menu, or a menu for a list box or a menu bar.
 *
 * @class tinymce.ui.DropMenu
 * @extends tinymce.ui.Menu
 * @example
 * // Adds a menu to the currently active editor instance
 * var dm = tinyMCE.activeEditor.controlManager.createDropMenu('somemenu');
 * 
 * // Add some menu items
 * dm.add({title : 'Menu 1', onclick : function() {
 *     alert('Item 1 was clicked.');
 * }});
 * 
 * dm.add({title : 'Menu 2', onclick : function() {
 *     alert('Item 2 was clicked.');
 * }});
 * 
 * // Adds a submenu
 * var sub1 = dm.addMenu({title : 'Menu 3'});
 * sub1.add({title : 'Menu 1.1', onclick : function() {
 *     alert('Item 1.1 was clicked.');
 * }});
 */
```

Comment: This code seems to create the DropMenu object but doesn't yet add it. What kind of code would be needed to add the dropdown to the toolbar?

Answer (score 1):

this adds a button so you just need to tweak it to make a drop down box

```
// register button
function register_button($buttons) {  
   array_push($buttons, "btn");   
   return $buttons;  
}  

// add button
function add_button() {  
   if ( current_user_can('edit_posts') &&  current_user_can('edit_pages') )  
   {  
     add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'add_plugin');  
     add_filter('mce_buttons', 'register_button');  
   }  
}  

// add plugin
function add_plugin($plugin_array) {  
    $plugin_array['btn'] =get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/customcodes.js';

   return $plugin_array;  
}
```

you will then need to add the to the js file

```
(function() {  
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.btn', {  
        init : function(ed, url) {  
            ed.addButton('btn', {  
                title : 'Add a btn',  
                image : url+'/btn.png',  
                onclick : function() {  
                     ed.selection.setContent('[btn]');  
                }  
            });  
        },  
        createControl : function(n, cm) {  
            return null;  
        },  
    });  
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('btn', tinymce.plugins.btn);  
})();
```