# Creating select dropdown box for font sizes in a custom ui

Tags: tinymce

Below is taken from the TinyMCE website and their example for making a custom ui. The problem is that the example only demonstrates what to do if you want buttons. What if you want to implement your own select dropdown for font sizes etc.. I don't even want anything custom really, just a default  tag will do. How can I do it?

```
tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "textareas",
        content_css : "../css/custom_theme_editor.css",
        theme_advanced_font_sizes: "10px,12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px",
    font_size_style_values : "10px,12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px",
        language: false, // Prevents language packs from loading

        theme: function(editor, target) {
            var dom = tinymce.DOM, editorContainer;

            // Generate UI
            editorContainer = dom.insertAfter(dom.create('div', {style: ''},
                '<div>' +
                    '<button data-mce-command="bold">bold</button>' +
                    '<button data-mce-command="italic">italic</button>' +
                    '<button data-mce-command="underline">underline</button>' +
                    '<button data-mce-command="fontsizeselect">font size</button>' +  
                    '<button data-mce-command="mceInsertContent" data-mce-value="Hello">Insert Hello</button>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div style="border: 1px dashed #cccccc;"></div>'
            ), target);

            // Set editor container size to target element size
            dom.setStyle(editorContainer, 'width', target.offsetWidth);

            // Bind events for each button
            tinymce.each(dom.select('button', editorContainer), function(button) {
                dom.bind(button, 'click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    // Execute editor command based on data parameters
                    editor.execCommand(
                        dom.getAttrib(e.target, 'data-mce-command'),
                        false,
                        dom.getAttrib(e.target, 'data-mce-value')
                    );
                });
            });

            // Register state change listeners
            editor.onInit.add(function() {
                tinymce.each(dom.select('button', editorContainer), function(button) {
                    editor.formatter.formatChanged(dom.getAttrib(button, 'data-mce-command'), function(state) {
                        state ? $(button).addClass("tiny-mce-button-clicked") : $(button).removeClass("tiny-mce-button-clicked");

                    });
                });
            });

            // Return editor and iframe containers
            return {
                editorContainer: editorContainer,
                iframeContainer: editorContainer.lastChild,

                // Calculate iframe height: target height - toolbar height
                iframeHeight: target.offsetHeight - editorContainer.firstChild.offsetHeight
            };
        }
    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Custom Dropdown Box in Tinymce in Wordpress for Shortcodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439232/create-custom-dropdown-box-in-tinymce-in-wordpress-for-shortcodes)